# Rails Como hacer test de integracion luego de instalar devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, test, devise

Estoy haciendo un test de integracion que antes de instalar devise funcionaba. Ahora arroja error por una llave duplicada. Tratando de insertar un usuario. La cosa es que estoy haciendo y probando los test es para un modelo Categoria que no tiene ni siquiera asociacion.
Les dejo el codigo y el error. Gracias

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateCategoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

 test "get new category form and create category" do
     get new_category_path
     assert_template 'categories/new'
     assert_difference 'Category.count', 1 do
         post categories_path, params: { category: { name: "measure tension", description: "This is the Category for measure tension"} }
         follow_redirect!
     end
     assert_template 'categories/index'
     assert_match "measure tension", response.body
 end

end
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 14544
Run options: --seed 57420

# Running:

E

Error:
CreateCategoriesTest#test_get_new_category_form_and_create_category:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «index_users_on_email»
DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (email)=().
: DELETE FROM "categories";
DELETE FROM "users";
INSERT INTO "categories" ("id", "name", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (980190962, 'MyString', 'MyText', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344'), (298486374, 'MyString', 'MyText', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.457344');
INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (980190962, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209'), (298486374, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209', '2020-03-06 20:25:00.463209')


Error:
CreateCategoriesTest#test_get_new_category_form_and_create_category:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass



bin/rails test test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:5



Finished in 0.023791s, 42.0323 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Agradezco la ayuda. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en el `users.yml` que, si esta en blanco o tiene dos usuarios con el mismo email, arroja error, ya que tengo seteados los fixtures todos.

Si se comenta la linea de los `fixtures:all` también se soluciona. Pero preferí agregar los usuarios en el archivo `users.yml`.